# How to find out the worker/socket number from within app code running in thin web server

Tags: ruby, sockets, rack, thin

I've recently started using a centralized log server (graylog2) and have been happily adding info to be logged.

I'm also running several Ruby web applications (Rails and Sinatra) under the thin web server, each with a number of workers (1-4). The workers listen to UNIX sockets.

I'd like to log which of the thin workers (i.e. worker #1, worker #2) is serving the request. The idea is to check that all workers get roughly the same load from the load balancer.

There seems to be no HTTP header or ENV variable set up for this in thin.

Anyone know if this information can be made available to the web app running inside the worker ?

Comment: every worker should have a different pid. is that enough?

Comment: Not quite what I need, but it would be a start...I guess you could get to the pid over the Ruby process API...